# SQLite: express the difference as days, hours, minutes between two given dates

Tags: sqlite, datetime, datediff

I am trying to express the difference of two given dates in days, hours, and minutes (like 1 day, 6 hours, 17 minutes.) as SQLite query output. I have `entryin` and `entryout` as `datetime` fields in a SQLitedatabase. I tried all combinations of `julianday` and `strftime` but still running into rough weather.

I tried `strftime('%d %H:%M', julianday(entryout)-julianday(entryin))`. For a row the values are `2011-11-10 11:46`, and `2011-11-09 09:00`. but the output is `25 14:46` instead of `01 02:46`.

Can some one help me with this, or point me correct logic for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT
    CAST((strftime('%s', '2011-11-10 11:46') - strftime('%s', '2011-11-09 09:00')) / (60 * 60 * 24) AS TEXT) || ' ' ||
    CAST(((strftime('%s', '2011-11-10 11:46') - strftime('%s', '2011-11-09 09:00')) % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60) AS TEXT) || ':' ||
    CAST((((strftime('%s', '2011-11-10 11:46') - strftime('%s', '2011-11-09 09:00')) % (60 * 60 * 24)) % (60 * 60)) / 60 AS TEXT);
```

Comment: Good answer Bill, to improve it and not to worry about too many '((' you could use /3600 for hours, %3600/60 for minutes and %60 for seconds

Comment: How to get yaer and month?

Comment: @EngrWaseemArain Unfortunately there is no easy, short solution for years and months because one month can have 28, 29, 30 or 31 days and one year can have 365 or 366 days.