# Sqlite get records by hour

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to make a query to get records between specified hours. For example, i want to get all records between 00:00 and 01:00 for all days. So, the date does not matter but hours. How to do that?

I have done this, but it only return for certain dates.

```
Select name from my_table where date_column> beginning and date_column< end
```

Here beginning and end are in millisecond. Also my date_column is stored in millisecond format.

Comment: Show what you have done till now. If you don't know where to start, google it and come back only when you have some problem or confusion.

Comment: @Nabin, I added what i have done till now.

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075973/sqlite-express-the-difference-as-days-hours-minutes-between-two-given-dates

Comment: @Nabin, it is a sqlite query, how to use alarm manager for this?

Comment: @CoKoder sorry I miss read your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `strftime()`:

```
Select name
from my_table
where strftime('%H', date_column) = '00';
```

This just checks the hour.  You could use `'%H:%M:%S'` if you wanted more granularity.

EDIT:

You do not have a date time value.  You have something else.  It looks like a Unix epoch time measured in milliseconds rather than seconds.  If so, the following should work:

```
Select name, datetime(date_column/1000, 'unixepoch')
from my_table
where strftime('%H', datetime(date_column/1000, 'unixepoch')) = '19';
```

However, none of the times are at hour 3.  You may need to convert using your localtime.

Comment: it does not return any records.

Comment: what is 0 in your query? that means 00:00?

Comment: @CoKoder . . . That was a stupid mistake on my part, the arguments were in the wrong order.  The `0` is the hour of the day.  This function is the equivalent of `hour(datetime)` or `extract(hour from datetime)` or `datepart(hour, datetime)` in other databases, except the SQLite version returns a string instead of an integer.

Comment: my date is stored in milliseconds form, can i still use your query? How do I specify the time range? E.x: 00:00 to 01:00.

Comment: I created a sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/7161d/3 , it seems it does not work

Comment: it seems after your edit it works, but how about 2 hours interval instead of 1 hour?

Comment: @CoKoder . . . Just use `in` or `between`.